# how to host in iis7?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project and I want to host in IIS7 on Windows 7.

How and where do I setup my default page?

Comment: [http://learn.iis.net/](http://learn.iis.net/) [http://www.netomatix.com/development/IIS7Configuration3.aspx](http://www.netomatix.com/development/IIS7Configuration3.aspx)

Comment: See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Answer (score 1):

for installing iis7 try following the steps in this link:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

after installing iis7, check the properties from the left pane by going to

ComputerName > Sites > Default Web Site > right click, manage website, advanced settings

here you should see the path where the files are